# Capture multiple groups in the same line

Tags: regex

I would like to split a multiline text by "."
Somethigne like this:

input:

```
aaaa aaaa aaaa. bbbb bbbb bbbb.
cccc cccc. dddd.
```

required result:

```
[0]: aaaa aaaa aaaa.
[1]: bbbb bbbb bbbb.
[2]: cccc cccc.
[3]: dddd.
```

It's a simple think to do but I could not do this.. I dont even know how to search this in google.
I've tried many examples like `/(.+[.])/igm` but it gets results with full line text, not splitted by "."

How can I do this?

Comment: `+` is usual greedy by default. add a `?` like `.+?` to change to non-greedy OR change `.+` to `[^.]+` to match all non `.` characters

Comment: In your example, you're simply "matching" a pattern. What you do with that group later is key. So, in which language are you doing this? and are you sure it is not easier to just use a language feature to split, rather than regex?

Comment: If you're using PHP, then use the `explode` function.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php  Also, are you actually trying to extract sentences?  That could throw a wrinkle in things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a capture group:

```
([^.]*.)  with g flag
```

if you want to skip the space after the `. (dot)`:

```
([^.]*.)\s?
```

see result here:

https://regex101.com/r/cY7gU9/1

Answer (score 1):

Your `.+` Will match ANY character, including the literal character '.'. So, that's why it matches the whole thing. You need to specify that it should accept one or more characters that are not a '.' followed by a '.'. So, your regex would be: `/([^.\n]+[.])/igm`. By the way, I also included stopping at newlines, since your desired output didn't include the newline. You could remove this if you wanted to. Here's a demo: http://www.regexpal.com/?fam=93474.